# iOS Export Archive Provisioning Profile List

Tags: ios, xcode, ad-hoc-distribution

For some reason I cannot figure out how to clear out this list. Everytime I add a new device and then re-download my distribution profile from Apple it loads a new entry in this list.

How can I clear this list? Really I should only have 1 dev and 1 distrib profile.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go into your keychain and delete the file. then they will disappear from this list.